# Shouldn't the loop append one, then two, then three numbers to the matrix?

Tags: for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

```
def matrixInput():
  matrix=[]
  print("Enter the elements row-wise: ")
  for i in range(0,3):
    a = []
    for j in range(0,3):
      a.append(int(input()))
      matrix.append(a) #this line should have been back one tab, this was a typo mistake...however left like this, the code is running in an unexpected way
  print((matrix))


print(matrixInput())

#this code's output:
Enter the elements row-wise: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
None

#shouldn't it print:
#[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[4],[4,5],[4,5,6],[7],[7,8][7,8,9]]...??
```

So I'm a new developer in first year UNI. While completing a lab I made a typo mistake that caused a weird output. I fixed the mistake but I'm still interested in the results of the typo. It produced an unexpected result. I've thought about it for days and just can't figure why the result is different from what I'd expected.

#What am I missing???

Comment: Please, don't post your code as a picture. Use code blocks instead

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I haven't had much interaction with this site.

Comment: I don't see why this would be surprising - you're appending each `a` to `matrix` three times rather than once.

Comment: Yeah but the first time you append, what is a...isn't it [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the variables for array as a memory location, similar to a reference. As you are adding array "a" to matrix, matrix array only remembers the address of a, as you append data to "a" and making changes to "a", the previous index in matrix which are referencing "a" actually changes. In the first loop, every iteration resets the memory of array "a", so only 3 copies of array "a" are saved in matrix.

Lets assume when you set a = [], we have a new memory location for a, we have total of a,a2,and a3. The matrix array at the end of the loop has values [a,a,a,a2,a2,a2,a3,a3,a3], because you print the end result after all iterations, the values each a,a2,a3 refer to will be the same.

If you find it hard to understand, try run this code

```
matrix = []
a = []
a.append(2)
matrix.append(a)   # matrix has [a]   a = [2]
print(matrix)      # matrix prints as [2]
a.append(3)
matrix.append(a)   # matrix has [a,a] a = [2,3]
print(matrix)      # matrix prints as [[2,3],[2,3]] instead of [[2],[2,3]], because matrix only knows [a,a] and a is [2,3] when this line is called
```

Comment: the result of this code is 2 then 2,3.... shouldn't it be the same with the code above?

Comment: to put it in simple words, as you make changes to "a", the already stored result of "a" will change accordingly.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the matrix is storing "a" and not the input "2" or "3". Right? I think I get it....Thanks alot. This seems to be an important key thing to note for the future.

Comment: yes, because a is an array and array uses memory location/address instead of fixed values like an integer does. I recommend taking a programming course in C or C++, then you'll understand what all this is about.

Comment: Our course in C has just began.... It seems I may need to supplement it with some Youtube videos too. Thanks again.